# Corporate Policy Tracking

Tags: cms, wiki

I'm looking for an efficient system for recording, authorizing and storing company policies for a small business of under 50 employees. I've looked into a couple different Wiki (MediaWiki) and CMS systems (WordPress), but I'm just not sure.

An example workflow would be, one board member developed a policy, which then has to be reviewed and approved by the entire board.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Do you mean something specific by "policy", like ACL for some specific tool?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider [JIRA from Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira), you can opt for a hosted or self-hosted setup. It will allow you to assign tasks (ie. development of a policy) and then within each task, create sub-tasks (ie. review by 1 or more person(s)). Quite possibly overkill but it will get the job done and allow for tracking of the entire process.